# R Image Processing - Calculate the crop greenness

Tags: r, image-processing, rgb

my goal is to calculate the greenness of a potato crop as shown on the image

[image]

To this end, I first perform following steps: 
- Load the RGB image
- Extract the R, G and B bands 
- Calculate the desired Greenness index for the whole picture

```
img<-load.image(image.files[i]) 
R<-R(img)
G<-G(img)
B<-B(img)
ExGreen<-2*G-R-B
```

This results in following type of image:

[image]

To assess the greenness index of the potato crop I now have to remove the background (i.e. soil) from the foreground (i.e. the crop) and then calculate the mean greenness index value.

To remove the background I applied the 'threshold' function of the EBImage package, as follows:

```
ExGreen<-(threshold(ExGreen,thr="auto",approx=FALSE,adjust=1))
```

This function removes the background very well but renders me a black and white image (the potato crop turns white as shown in the image below)

[image]

Consequently I cannot calculate the mean greenness index of the potato crop/foreground as my ExGreen values have have gone missing...

So now I'm wondering how I can render the background black without turning crop pixels white..

Comment: What values do the cells take after thresholding? You could simply use your second image as a mask for the first; look at the `mask` function from the raster package. Something like `mask(ExGreen, ExGreen_threshold)` should do it, with the `maskvalue` argument set to the black value (0? 1?) in your second image.

Comment: The threshold function indeed return 'true' and 'false'.. combining both images as you suggested will indeed do the trick! Thank you!